# what is the correct way to test if a type is an allocator?

Tags: c++, c++14, type-traits, allocator

Writing `allocator_traits<T>::value_type` in a SFINAE context seems like a workable way to test if a type `T` is, in fact, an allocator. This is however not particularly elegant and I have been burned by corner cases in the past.

Therefore my question: how best might one implement an `is_allocator<T>` traits containing a `::value` of true in the case where T is an allocator and ::false otherwise?

Comment: But what **is** an allocator? :) Allocator us user-defined concept, not language-defined. In other words, what would you do with allocator which you wouldn't do with other type? In second set of other words, allocators have very specific usage. I find it hard to imagine a scenario, where particular type could be used as allocator if it is an allocator, or in some other fashion when it is not. In a third set of other words, is it an XY problem?

Comment: You could check if it has the allocate function.

Comment: @NathanOliver yes, however, I believe that a type with a member function allocate but no ::value_type for which there is no specialization of allocator_traits is not an allocator

Comment: @SergeyA I agree that one can obviously only check the publich interface syntax and not ones expectations on the implementation. However this is for a super generic context where I just want to validate that a type supports the allocators syntactic requirements.

Comment: @odinthenerd since I believe, there is no alternative (i.e. when it is used in allocator context, it should be an allocator) I'd say, just the interface. If it happened to miss the functions or types, compiler error will be generated. This is the best advice I can give.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Writing `allocator_traits<T>::value_type` in a SFINAE context seems like a workable way to test if a type `T` is, in fact, an allocator.

I don't think this is sufficient. This would just check if `T` has a `value_type` and is rebindable. Both libstdc++ and libc++ would consider `std::map<int, int>` to be an allocator in that model.

The standard has [a table of requirements](http://eel.is/c++draft/allocator.requirements#tab:utilities.allocator.requirements) for what constitutes an `Allocator`. I think your best bet would be just to check several of the expressions for validity, namely:

- `X::value_type`
- `a.allocate(n)` being valid and returning an `X::pointer`
- `a.deallocate(p, n)` being valid

(where `X` is the type you are checking, `a` is an `X&`, and `n` is a value of type `allocator_traits<X>::size_type`)

If there's a type that checks all those boxes and still isn't an allcoator, well... ¯\_(ツ)_/¯.

Comment: your right, I was under the wrong impression that allocator traits actually did some validation on the default case so it would its self SFINAE in case you give it garbage but that seems to not be the case

Answer (score 1):

For completeness sake here's the C++20 concept for @Barry's answer:

```
template <typename Allocator> 
concept is_allocator = requires(Allocator a, typename Allocator::value_type* p) {
    { a.allocate(0) } -> std::same_as<decltype(p)>;
    { a.deallocate(p, 0) } -> std::same_as<void>;
};
```

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIAMykrgAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxBKBAA6oCoRODB7evnrJqY4CoeFRLLHxAJy2mPb5DEIETMQEmT5%2BgXaYDul1DQSFkTFxCbb1jc3ZXMM9fcWlIGUAlLaoXsTI7Bzm/mHI3lgA1Cb%2Bbk4KBMSYrIfYJhoAgpvbu5gHR6fEYcBXN/dmWww7Xn2hzcbBYJAAnl87g9/k8XiDMGDiOCAPrnBTLVaYKE/P4AoFHABuHSIxBxMPxz2BaH%2BmESBAU5N%2Bj0BVKOXkctEIkP82D2AHoAFR7LA7QliPaC/nfb4ERGJAxy%2BEEcGJRisZ63Wi0VCiUlXA53Glrel7PAKFFiHV6kgvAAie3OAEcvHh0RAtdamKS9kxSHsVWrmGw9p7dd6SCAQOLvJgUYHMMLEvMDgB2Kx3PZZtMWX0AOit4blEA0KZMqYdAFoDad0FGFBrLYyjqLaAmIMmvv4M7dszn81hC3rMB3/aW01WawQ6yAG2wm8DCag8Oguz3y3bDuu7nKWArvWy3Ang88ACo4t5eBx7ACy4LDNuIOe%2Bfa8qSMexjXjjCfte3P3YvtmTAcqgvrakWI61vWeAAF4/nsqTwSm1a8v%2BgpbkBWYgUQIoXBBw4QKegr%2BtBs5wQhSGYChBpLiumHQhWDH3HcYQEHsLBMGEEBlumWF7G%2BHyhlwf5kUOEZkkcbFrvxgkfrcZiidOUaJCw8QgMktDgkiiQIHgyCWgREnAmR0TgnKMmZtmcnAHsuaHA6d4PsZUmCJZvbWe%2BtluEpM5vB8zEylZWZ4FQew0qcmCqIkxAQOahlevqRy3FwVy8T2fZ9mRaAcvCwIHGYZgpWaCi%2Bgw4GJSQ5iKcC%2BVka4tDMX2G78aF4UCJF0WxfF4lJW4Clpc%2BwWZdlyzsbVRwFUVinmmVFVFlVhV5ZN9UMOgjWAcNLXDW1EVyl1cUWr1VVHFYvLpfxWXKSgY3LT51W5rNhjzY%2B1V3Yh10NU12bbR5IVhXtUUxYdCULZJbhuIN5YZZlWajblE33YVPlPeVx1kktiMfTOX2bX9E4yhWHCLLQnAAKy8H4HBaKQqCcJDljWIhmJrAV/g8KQBCaMTiwANYgGTGj6JwkiU9ztOcLwCggELXPU8TpBwLAMCIDde50HE5CUGg6v0PEwAKMwiQKAgqAEKQWCEvpmAAGp4JgADuADyQacBzNBtnE0sQNE4vRGEDTgm7vD%2B8wyJO9E2gksHpA62wghOwwWni1g0ReMAbhWtL3C8FgnFGOI8sW26JJ4MS2c01FHQcusNNsVU4tctExCBx4WDi2ceAsMHixUAYBt247LuMDH/CCCIYjsFIMiCIoKjqEXugTAYRgoNY1j6Hg0TS5AiyoPS6TZ5WtYOaYjOWGYGh7JWTsKLwqDEsQ7xYDvPGVNU6QuGtYx%2BBMIRhP0EogwJi5DSAIH%2BOQUhgIYNMAY8QJjtE6AIbooxPAtD0IgmoKDegAJmMAyYqCsi/wITgoocCJCLAxCsNYFDhYcApqQKmNM6YcD2KoAAHAANkrJwyQexgDIGQHsCAZwvAMF5imCAuBCC2k2FweYvA5ZaHmHzAWQtSYcFFqQbuZNJB5kkGUVMZQNBGIMUYkxFQmH30lrYGWnNuaLCVqrMaiQORawgDrRIGtiARA1JwDh3DeH8MEXsLg/g8wc0wPgUkK49Bj2EKIcQ094lzzUOLJepAHYt0SD3OhDCrESw4E7Dkrj2KoDCgEnhfCBFCJEcQMREjhEeF1nENm8jFEOMWAgC4WB4hvw0Vo7ukgyZ5kFpfMol8xkaAmRMApLCpZ2KUTzUg/NBZ0P8GLIu8z7HyxUXQswmzmE2KWXsx%2BqRnCSCAA%3D%3D%3D)