# Allocator type inferred as const char* for some reason

Tags: c++, templates, allocator

I have an URL class that takes a templated `StringType` to store data. The allocator may also be provided using the `Allocator` template argument, if not it is inferred from the `StringType`. However: This fails as for some reason I'm getting `const char*` in the mix. I'm pretty sure it's a stupid oversight on my part, but I can't get behind it:

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIAKwAbKSuADJ4DJgAcj4ARpjEEgCcpAAOqAqETgwe3r4BwemZjgLhkTEs8YlcKXaYDtlCBEzEBLk%2BfkG2mPYlDE0tBGXRcQnJts2t7fldCpNDESOVYzUAlLaoXsTI7BzmAMwRyN5YANQm%2B25Oc8SYrBfYJhoAggdHJ5jnlzcRwA9PrzMhwYxy8ZwubjYLBIAE9/i83iCPl83AA3epEYjw14vAiYFipAx4lEEGGpRisT5NYi/AAqZMwpFOpPJzDYp2etFoqFEmOxNy8DlOAEUvAkYecAOxWBEvU7y05zdAgEDohwkCFKlWpJh4LGXal0hlMw1Genkh6kAEKm3Mhlsz5akBibm8kgAfQIxF1BAUEM5rqYfP22BVeIJRM%2Bt1iEXQ7pdPM1BGVIB1eohpuA5sZp0z2f%2BIYepwAjmLiDD3RcZa9JQARKsAgHhwlBz4QlkU9l5hlfWuK5Mqn5GJkdh0crk8oMkXt21mU3Neo3klUJt3ET0M/lewUEU5yABKoSl1ZtB9CEADk8xp1XU%2BIM5M0sftdW1tt8pApxYMJuj4sN4nNdnzfeU/2A2VnlPQ8ICdIdgHdVE8EwAB3U4tloJlLzXADA2vC4%2BzAutXzld9Tk/M8IFvTFiMghUwJI99vxuGd0IbBipXrCCQJFMs4QNRczWNcdcI1EMS14tjaPlbtyS/H8vUk4D9mrAEIl3FhdQYCBVmPbizzk9CHzMMxkNMgA6YBUFQYB6DM5AEHMMxFLrDh1loTh/F4PwOC0UhUE4NxrGsRVNm2NsgR4UgCE0Vz1gAawCDR9E4SQvJivzOF4BQQCS6KfNc0g4FgGBEBQVACToBJyEoNAKvoRJgC4fYuFILBEJ2AA1JDkIAeVZThIpoWg8WIbKIFidKY2YcsBt4KaWhhHrYm0DFZtIWq2EEHqGFoGF0qwWIvGANwXWy7heCwDSjHEfLWr1DE8HRM7fMwVR6i8PF0rUnp0toPBYm9csPCwdLFxYWb1ioAxgAULqUL6xg1v4QQRDEdgpBkQRFBUdRbt0FqDCMFAgssfR/uyyB1lQVI%2BjOgBaJV8NMSxrDMDRTjpnqFF4VB0WIGksAp7Tul6bIXAYdxPA6PQwkWCoqj0IosgEaY/BapW%2BmGeWVhFh6BAGKYpfyFq6gafX5i10ZqgmQZVb0OZBkt5ZqnWBRQp2CQ3I8tLbv8jhTlUAAOQI6cCSRTmAZBkFOJqzK4U4IFwQhpwOLhVl4PKtFWeLEuSjhUtIcH/EkMzJCSSUkg0Cuy4rquUm83y/aynKopi9YitKzYCFSD7qogWrUkq4gokpTgg5DsOI6jmP9jj3hMHwTE8GVFrkeEURxAxtfsbUdL8dIZDvVSCG8880gG55zgeo%2Bnvd1QKgA%2BD0Pw8j6PY/jiAPDqhJzgi9PW/ytnUgCA7hYESMLdy%2BdeDg0kP4My/gNBsySGzBBSCzAtQvhlDgzdcptxzggvO%2BwfaN0ygArOXsOBmGIZfbBZDYqkD5pkZwkggA%3D%3D)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

template <typename StringType, typename Allocator>
struct Query {

    std::vector<std::pair<StringType, StringType>,
        typename std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::template rebind_alloc<std::pair<StringType, StringType>>> query_;
};

template <typename StringType = std::string, typename Allocator = typename StringType::allocator_type>
struct URL {
    URL(Allocator allocator = {})
        : mystr{ allocator}
    {}

    URL(std::string_view url, Allocator allocator = {})
        : URL(allocator)
    {
        mystr = url;
    }


    Query<StringType, Allocator> query;
    StringType mystr;
};

int main() {
    URL myurl = "www.google.ch";
}
```

Yields (among others):

```
<source>:10:110:   required from 'struct Query<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, const char*>'
<source>:26:34:   required from 'struct URL<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, const char*>'
<source>:31:17:   required from here
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.1.0/include/c++/13.1.0/bits/alloc_traits.h:94:11: error: no type named 'type' in 'struct std::__allocator_traits_base::__rebind<const char*, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >, void>'
   94 |     using __alloc_rebind
      |           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Where is the `const char*` coming from?

Comment: `"www.google.ch"` is treated as an allocator, the first ctor is called and `Allocator = const char*`. Why should `std::string_view` be a batter match than `Allocator`? You need to add some restrictions for that template argument.

Comment: @EvgsupportsModeratorStrike Ahh that makes sense! What would you suggest? Is there something like an allocator concept I can use?

Comment: I guess you'll need your own concept, see [What is the correct way to test if a type is an allocator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51879797/what-is-the-correct-way-to-test-if-a-type-is-an-allocator)

Comment: @EvgsupportsModeratorStrike Done that, now I get a different error: https://godbolt.org/z/dvqTY75E1. It appears the std::string_view constructor can't be selected.

Comment: For the last problem see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59469582).

Answer (score 0):

There are two options to solve this issue:

- constrain the constructor taking an `Allocator` so that it can only be called with a valid allocator
- create additional constructors that win in overload resolution

The first option can be done by going through the list of expressions that an [*Allocator* (named requirement)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Allocator) must support. See also: [what is the correct way to test if a type is an allocator?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51879797/5740428).

However, this isn't all that simple, and many expressions are optional. The standard library usually doesn't have concepts for larger requirements like *Allocator* or *Conctainer* due to how massive they would be.

Instead, you can add another constructor:

```cpp
// note: Take allocator by const& instead of moving, because std::string
//       and other containers don't support move semantics for allocators
//       anyway.
URL(const char* str, const Allocator& allocator = {})
// note: we shouldn't be passing this allocator into the string; it has its own
//       allocator that may be different
    : mystr(str), query(allocator) {}
```

In the original code, a string literal would have resulted in calling `URL(Allocator)`, because the constructor taking `std::string_view` isn't eligible. It would be an implicit conversion `const char[] -> std::string_view -> URL`, but this cannot be done in one step.

Furthermore, it would make much more sense to make the constructor taking an `Allocator` `explicit`, because we don't want an implicit conversion from an allocator to a URL; that conversion makes no sense:

```cpp
explicit URL(const Allocator& allocator = {})
// ...
```

You can see that [the constructor of `std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) deals with the issue of allocators in the exact same way.

Comment: Adding a constructor that takes `const char*` somewhat defeats the purpose of what `std::string_view` was introduced for. And what will happen if you pass `char*` instead of `const char*`? This should be a valid input, but without `Allocator` restrictions, the first ctor would be called again.

Comment: @EvgsupportsModeratorStrike we don't actually have a choice if we want implicit conversions. We cannot call a constructor taking `std::string_view` via `= "literal"`.

Comment: But we could make a ctor that takes generic `String` (`<template class String>`) and then do conversion inside, similar to how [`std::filesystem::path` ctor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/path) is implemented.